# Are there in fact no laws of nature?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, natural-law

Are there in fact no laws of nature? This thought just occurred to me. Let me explain. We call certain true statements about the physical world laws of nature. But maybe the distinction between true statements that are laws and true statements that are not laws, is just an arbitrary distinction. Maybe all there are, are just true statements about the physical world. Is this the case? Also, have any philosophers argued for this view?

Comment: You are mixing two ontological problems: existence dependently and independently of the mind. Laws are basically rules, rules exist only in the mind; rules are the way we describe patterns. Saying that "there are no laws of nature" is correct, if we consider that nature does not depend on our minds, but it's wrong if we accept that natural patterns can be described with such rules.

Comment: "maybe the distinction between true statements that are laws and true statements that are not laws, is just an arbitrary distinction." In a sense yes: laws of nature are so according to some scientific theory.

Comment: No, there are no laws of nature. The so-called laws are a set of observations about how nature is seen to 'behave'. They are written by humans, and nature is not obliged to 'obey' them. They are predictions, an approximation of the observed behaviour, as demonstrated by Einstein modifiying Newton's 'laws'. They express our *model* of nature, our *understanding*. It is sheer arrogance to suppose otherwise. Sometimes people quote the 'laws of nature' as if they personally wrote them.

Comment: Most philosophers of science are inclined to be realists about laws of nature, so they would maintain that there are laws, though there is some disagreement about what account to give of them. In my experience a lot of scientists also speak of scientific laws. A good starting point would be to read the article on laws of nature in the Stanford Encyclopedia https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/